# Adding ajaxchimp to a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, mailchimp

I'm trying to get ajaxchimp working (https://github.com/scdoshi/jquery-ajaxchimp).

Here's my code:

```
<form class="pure-form center">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email_input_id"><input class="pure-input-1-3" placeholder=
        "Email" type="email" /></label>
    </fieldset><button class="whitehomepage" type="submit"> go!</button>
</form>
```

And the javascript:

```
$('#pure-form').ajaxChimp({
    callback: mailchimpCallback,
    url: "http://xxxxxx.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3959eeadb32e02b85a792e21c&id=6d7613df26"
});

function mailchimpCallback(resp) {
    alert("callback")
}
```

Unfortunately it's not working for me. Any ideas?

I'm using jquery 1.10.2 and it recommends jquery 1.9.1 could that be an issue?

Thanks

edit: OMG. I'm such an idiot. Should be .pure-form not #pure-form. That'll fix it.

Comment: check my edited answer my friend

Answer (score 0):

No need to use https://github.com/scdoshi/jquery-ajaxchimp .

Try this one.

```
<form class="pure-form center">
    <script>
    $( "#whitehomepage" ).click(function() {
    formData = {
        u: "3959eeadb32e02b85a792e21c",
        id: "6d7613df26"
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://fiercelycurious.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post",
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //success handler
        },
        error: function() {
            //error handler
        }
    });
    });
    </script>

    <fieldset>
        <label for="email_input_id"><input class="pure-input-1-3" placeholder=
        "Email" type="email" /></label>
    </fieldset><button class="whitehomepage" id="whitehomepage" type=
    "submit">go!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you explain a little more? I'm a javascript beginner... Do I use this in conjunction with the ajaxchimp code? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - I presume I'll need to attach this ajax to the form somehow or will copy and pasting this in will work? Thanks (sorry for the beginner questions!)

Comment: You just paste it into your form as long you use jquery :)

Comment: Hi, sorry - I updated the question with the code I'm using now. Still doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: Hmm - it reloads the page to my homepage. The email address doesn't get submitted to mailchimp though. Could there be a problem with using the JSONP url as per: https://github.com/scdoshi/jquery-ajaxchimp/blob/master/jquery.ajaxchimp.js ?